# Is there a way to force a custom datasource to start a new file when a file size limit is hit?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

We are building a tool in spark to process a terabytes of transaction data and produce a JSON report. There is a hard requirement to limit the size of any individual JSON file, along with other specific requirements concerning the JSON. To deal with the JSON formatting requirements we built a custom DataSource class (which extends the JsonFileFormat shipped with Spark).

However, I cannot find any documentation or API specs to specify file creation or file size limits. It looks like that's all being managed at a level below where I have any control.

Is that true, and if not, does anybody know how to split a file once it reaches a certain size?

```
Dataset<Row> dataframe = ...

dataframe.write()
  .format('com.company.custom.datasource')
  .options(...)
  .save('hdfs://host:port/path/to/directory');
```

Ideally, we'd have a writer that saves the partition data into it's JSON formatted file, but once we hit a certain number of bytes, it would close that file, and start a new one. Even if processing the same partition.

Alternatively, if there were some way to know how many bytes are in a partition, we could re-partition ahead of time.